# Set one property visible at a time in a Grid row in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, grid, visibility

I have a `Grid` which has multiple rows. In First row of my grid I have a `DataGrid` to show some content when my `Tree` is clicked.
If there is no content to the value clicked in the `TreeView` then NO-COntent should be displayed in `grid.row=0` instead of `DataGrid`.

How can I do that. I have set `Visibility` to `collapsed` to my `TextBox`. And I have made it `Visible` in code behind when there is No-Content.
It works fine when the TextBox has been placed anywhere, but not in the `Grid.Row=0.`

`XAML`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Name="grid" Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Name="horzspliter" Height="5"/>
        <RowDefinition Name="detailview" Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Height="23" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="textBlock1" Text="No-Content" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="500" />

    // Text Block Is not displayed in the Grid.Row="0"
    <my:DataGrid Grid.Row="0" />
</Grid>
```

`Code behind`

```
if (!File.Exists(path))
{               
    this.textBlock1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
else
{
    this.textBlock1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    //Do Datagrid Operations
}
```

How can I make it visible and my `DataGrid Hidden` in `Grid.Row=0` itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid is overlapping with your `TextBox`. You can set your grid visibility to `Collapsed` when you show the `TextBox` or change the declaration order of the `TextBox` with the `DataGrid` in your XAML and your TextBox will be rendered on top of your `DataGrid`.